# Deep link with # in url is not redirecting to app

Tags: android, url, deep-linking

I have a deep link URL that I want to match for a specific activity of my app:
`https://example.com/#/auth`

The problem is with *#* in my URL, when I omit it, deep-link works fine. but with # deep link is opening chrome instead of my app.

Here are the manifest meta tags:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/#/auth"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Using # probably screws up the parser, as # separates the path of a url from the anchor.  It has an actual meaning in the url.  Don't use it.  Likely the system is seeing the host as "example.com", the path as "" and the anchor as "/auth", which doesn't match that filter.

Comment: @GabeSechan
I can't remove # from the url because it's an external API I'm using, it must be there.
Is there a way to escape it in parser like what we do for Regex?